# How to use an internal DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

How to use an internal DbContext?
I wonder how can I hide the DbContext object so that other libraries of my project not directly access.

I put my DbContext as internal in the library, and apparently should work, however when I run the application, the following error appears:

The target context 'Context' is not constructible. Add a default constructor or Provide an Implementation of IDbContextFactory

Could someone help me?

My implementation of data layer is:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof (ConfigContext))]
internal class Context : DbContext
{
    internal Context()
        : base(ConfigDataBase.GetSqlServerString(ConfigZnfce.Instance.SqlServerInstance))
    {
    }
    //More code below
}


public class ConfigContext: DbConfiguration
{
    public ConfigContext()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"));
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient", System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
        SetDatabaseInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
        SetDatabaseInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());            
    }
}
```

I want all the other libraries are required to go through a unit of work and repositories in order to do any operation with the database

[SOLVED]

I left the Context class as "internal" and set the constructor as "public" as in the code below:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof (ConfigContext))]
internal class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base(ConfigDataBase.GetSqlServerString(ConfigZnfce.Instance.SqlServerInstance))
    {
    }
    //More code below
}
```

Comment: how did you implement your DbContext?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to hide your DbContext? You could wrap it into a repository pattern, which your other classes access then, but I still wouldn't make it internal.

Comment: What code throws that exception?

Comment: I edited the message and include the implementation of my context. I do not want a public context, because I do not want other libraries to access it directly, because I want to completely encapsulate the data layer. I do not want another developer without access to the source code of the data layer can save an entity using directly Context.SaveChanges () ...

Comment: Invert your project assemblies so that the code where you do not want DbContext to be used does not take a dependency on the EntityFramework assembly or the assembly where your DbContext is defined. Then you can make it public.

Comment: This would not prevent another developer make reference to the library and would add in his project a reference to the assembly EntityFramework. In this way he would have full access to the Context

Comment: Apparently my problem is with the Migration, more precisely in line:SetDatabaseInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Contexto, Configuration>());

Comment: This does not prevent a developer from using reflection to create an instance of the DbContext.

Comment: I am new to C#, please have any suggestions on how I can isolate it completely?

Comment: You can't. Best mitigation tactic is regular code reviews on developer commits.

Comment: @danludwig True on the reflection, but as an analogy, locked doors don't prevent people from entering your house, however, they do provide a pretty good indicator you don't want them in there.

Comment: I personally think that it's a valid task to make dbcontext internal. The internal EF libraries that are using public properties of the dbcontext through reflection might as well consider  internal properties. This is more important for obfuscation than for layer abstraction. I hope they implement this feature this way.

Comment: @danludwig - Its about a separation of concerns, not security. Your data layer should be in charge of data access and managing connections. These responsibilities should not be extended outside of your data layer. If the DBcontext is not exposed, you won't have developers misusing it and violating data access boundaries. You seem to be arguing against the very concept of access modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

The **virtual DBSet<>** properties on the DbContext class must be public (as you found out in your solution.

If you're using TT templates, you can make this happen by changing the **DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)** function.  Notice that the term **public** replaces the original **{0}** parameter in the string format.

```
public string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet) {
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "public virtual DbSet<{0}> {1} {{ get; set; }}",
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(entitySet.ElementType),
        _code.Escape(entitySet));
}
```

Now, you can have an internal DbContext, internal objects, and still have the public automatic properties so EF can do its data-binding.